# How to make a common function to fier an event

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have a grid and in that grid I have one save button in bottom. On click of save button I am opening window.

```
 {
     xtype: 'button',
     text: "Save",
     handler: function () {
         new Wind({
             title: "Change"
         }).show();
     }
 }
```

Then here is code for window.

```
Ext.ns();
Wind = Ext.extend(Ext.Window, {
    width: 350,
    height: 150,
    initComponent: function () {
        var p = this;
        Ext.apply(p, {
            modal: true,
            layout: {
                type: 'fit'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textarea',
                id: "ChangeText",
                name: 'reasonforallchanges',
            }],
            buttons: ['->', {
                text: "Save",
                width: 80,
                disabled: false,
                scope: this,
                handler: this.Savechange,
            }, {
                text: "cancel",
                name: 'cancelchanges',
                scope: p,
                handler: function () {
                    this.close();
                }
            }]
        });
        Wind.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    listeners: {
        show: function () {
            this.focus();
        }
    },
    onEsc: function () {
        this.close();
    },
    Savechange: function () {
        debugger;
        var modifiedTextCmp = Ext.getCmp('RFCText');
        modifiedTextCmp = modifiedTextCmp.fireEvent('click', modifiedTextCmp);
        var grid = Ext.getCmp('GRID');
        var gridstore = grid.getStore();
        var modifyRec = gridstore.modified;
        var ReasonDetail = modifyRec.getValue();
        for (var i = 0; i < modifyRec.length; i++) // Setting VAlue here
            modifyRec[i].set("ABC", modifiedReasonDetail);
        // updating store 
        this.close();
    },
});
```

So As you see I need call grid and update here, But I want to be make it generic window. Therefore I need to use save button in such a way that it fire some event but not in wind.js

Comment: It seems you need to open this window through different views & want to change that paritcular view on clicking save which has opened this window.

Comment: I am opening this window on click of save button of my grid. What are different view where I can open

Comment: I want to understand the meaning of generic here.. Do you want to reuse this window for other views also?

Comment: Yes. I want to use this window and buttons to other places as well.

Comment: So it seems you need to listen to save button click of window at a common place

Comment: I written window and its bbar buttons in separate js and calling that js in click of button which is in grid.